# Split string into tokens and save them in an array

Tags: c, split, strtok

How to split a string into an tokens and then save them in an array?

Specifically, I have a string `"abc/qwe/jkh"`. I want to separate `"/"`, and then save the tokens into an array.

Output will be such that

```
array[0] = "abc"
array[1] = "qwe"
array[2] = "jkh"
```

please help me

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char buf[] ="abc/qwe/ccd";
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, "/");
    char *array[3];

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, "/");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If i want to compare array[0] with array [1], what should i do?

Comment: You use another function from <string.h>: if (strcmp(array[0], array[1]) == 0) { // array[0] = array[1] }

Comment: This assumes the number of tokens is know.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `p = strtok (NULL, "/");`?

Comment: `strtok()` does not work well in multi-threaded programs, libraries nor in some other programs that may call `strtok()` a second time with a different strings without finishing the loop before. `strtok_r()` could be a better solution or write your own function when `strtok_r()` is not available.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

```
char string[] = "abc/qwe/jkh";
char *array[10];
int i = 0;

array[i] = strtok(string, "/");

while(array[i] != NULL)
   array[++i] = strtok(NULL, "/");
```

Comment: A null pointer may be specified as the first argument of strtok(), in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

Comment: Worked pretty good. just how to give a dynamic count if we dont know the numbers of slpit element..

Comment: Cant arrays not be initialized with a variable?

Comment: This puts 4 elements into the array, with NULL as the last one.

Comment: `strtok()` is not a good solution, because it requires variables that are not on the stack nor heap.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 And where are those variables then? 

Comment: @l33t `static` variables, this causes problems when `strtok()` is called from multiple places. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Why `strtok()` is a bad idea

Do not use `strtok()` in normal code, `strtok()` uses `static` variables which have some problems. There are some use cases on embedded microcontrollers where `static` variables make sense but avoid them in most other cases. `strtok()` behaves unexpected when more than 1 thread uses it, when it is used in a interrupt or when there are some other circumstances where more than one input is processed between successive calls to `strtok()`.
Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Splits the input by the / character and prints the content in between
//the / character. The input string will be changed
void printContent(char *input)
{
    char *p = strtok(input, "/");
    while(p)
    {
        printf("%s, ",p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "abc/def/ghi:ABC/DEF/GHI";
    char *p = strtok(buffer, ":");
    while(p)
    {
        printContent(p);
        puts(""); //print newline
        p = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may expect the output:

```
abc, def, ghi,
ABC, DEF, GHI,
```

But you will get

```
abc, def, ghi,
```

This is because you call `strtok()` in `printContent()` resetting the internal state of `strtok()` generated in `main()`. After returning, the content of `strtok()` is empty and the next call to `strtok()` returns `NULL`.

### What you should do instead

You could use `strtok_r()` when you use a POSIX system, this versions does not need `static` variables. If your library does not provide `strtok_r()` you can write your own version of it. This should not be hard and Stackoverflow is not a coding service, you can write it on your own.

Comment: the OP never mentioned that they are in a multithreaded environment

Comment: @sijanec He also did not say he isn't. Please keep in mind that libraries should be multi threading save and putting a `strtok()` in a library is a bad idea. It is not only a problem in multithreading applications, as i wrote in my answer. Please read before you comment, thank you.