# How to split a string in c

Tags: c

I got first 5 digits that got the course serial number and then the course name
i want to split serial number from name to save in a struct
for example:

```
19234 Programming 101
```

I want to split to:

```
array[0]=19234
array[1]=programming 101
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `strtok()` do what you want?

Comment: @Barmar Do not use `strtok()`, `strtok()` uses `static` variables which makes it behave unpredictable in multithread environments and unexpected in cases where a subroutine and a higher routine both use `strtok()`. `strtok_r()` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple you can use the function strtok() as it mensioned before from barmar.
strtok() is a functiont that takes two parametres first you have to insert your string that you want to split and in the second parametre  you declare  inside in " **here** " what do you want to split .You can simple use " " for vacuum or commas and etc.
example :

```
int main(){
      char s[SIZE]="19234 Programming 101";
      char *c; // needs to be pointer

      c=strtok(s," ");
      printf("%s",c); // it will print this '19234'

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `strtok()`. I made an answer why you should not use `strtok()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472299/split-string-into-tokens-and-save-them-in-an-array/65107407#65107407

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 i will not follow that , sorry

Comment: If you are on Linux, Windows, Mac, Anroid, ... you could just replace `strtok()` with `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` and pass a pointer by pointer which you do not use for anything else. `char *context; strtok_r(s," ",&context);`.